# Rebind peek recorder's C-n key not to create new instance

Tags: emacs, video-editor

I installed [peek screen recorder](https://github.com/phw/peek) and employ it to record gif of Emacs operations.

In Emacs C-n invoke  next-line, it thus create anther new instance of peek window.

How could rebind peek's C-n but not create a new window?

[image]

Machine info:

```
OS: Ubuntu 19.10 x86_64 
Host: MacBookPro11,1 1.0 
Kernel: 5.3.0-24-generic 
Uptime: 7 hours, 54 mins 
Packages: 2601 (dpkg), 2 (snap) 
Shell: bash 5.0.3 
Resolution: 2560x1600 
DE: KDE 
WM: KWin 
Theme: Breeze [KDE], Breeze [GTK3] 
Icons: breeze [KDE], breeze [GTK3] 
Terminal: konsole 
Terminal Font: Noto Sans [GOOG] 9
```

Comment: Wow. I've been using emacs every day for almost 20 years and didn't even know about C-n. I've just always used the down arrow. I imagine using the down arrow isn't an option for you, you're too used to C-n?

Comment: ty, down arrow is a perfect alternative solution.